# I am trying to do a rotating screen python prank

Tags: python, python-3.x, rotation

Info:
I want to make the program rotate continuasly unless a spesific keyboard button is presed.
The thing is ... nothing happens when I press the button p for exapmle or whatever button i press. I will be glad if someone can help.:)

```
import time
import rotatescreen as rs
import keyboard

pd = rs.get_primary_display()
angel_list = [90, 180, 270, 0]

for i in range(5):
    for x in angel_list:
        pd.rotate_to(x)
        time.sleep(0.5)
    if keyboard.is_pressed("p"):
        pd.rotate_to(0)
        break
```

Comment: how long do you think it takes for this code to complete? and how long then it takes for you to press `p`? also if code completes then display returns to normal doesn't it? so again how long does it take for code to complete because maybe it completes so quickly that you don't get to press `p` nor you see any change

Comment: Oh, well there is a difference, because as you can see there is 0.5 seconds between every rotation. And i have tried multiple times chnaging the code, using while loops, bringing the range of the for loop up to a 100 and above and nothink works.

Comment: are you on windows`?

Comment: Yes, I am with Windows 10!

Comment: oh, missed the `sleep` but also do you understand that it tries registering you clicking `p` only every 2 seconds and for a short period of time? because it goes over all the angles (which there are 4) and after each rotation it sleeps for 0.5 seconds, after it goes over all of those angles it checks for `p`, then starts rotating again

Comment: Did you consider the possibility that you aren't pressing `p` *at the moment when* `keyboard.is_pressed("p")` runs?

Comment: Let me try doing it at the moment!

Comment: Wait ... It actually worked when i tried spamming it. Thank you!
But do you have any idea how i can make it check for the key pressing all the time? :)

Comment: first: maybe you should run `if` inside second `for`-loop. At this moment it checks key only after full rotation.

Comment: if you want it to check it really all the time, then you need to use `threading` and run the "checker" in a separate thread (`daemon=True`) and in a `while True:` loop

Comment: I think it is not working in the second for loop. it doesn't do anything anymore.

Comment: maybe you should use `keyboard.add_hotkey('p', function)` to register function which will be executed when you press `p` - and probably it should check it in separated thread. And your `function` may have to set some global variable which you would check in your loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`add_hotkey` before the loop that will call a function when pressed that will set a variable to `False` which will stop the loop (also since it stops it after a full rotation no matter when <kbd>p</kbd> is pressed, you don't need a separate check to turn screen back to normal):

```py
import time
import rotatescreen as rs
import keyboard


def stop():
    global run
    run = False


run = True
keyboard.add_hotkey('p', stop)
pd = rs.get_primary_display()
angel_list = [90, 180, 270, 0]

while run:
    for x in angel_list:
        pd.rotate_to(x)
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: That works perfectly for me, sir! Thank you very much <3.

Comment: Alright, I think i excpeted it! I am new to here tbh and don't know how thingd work. Thanks again!